# Removing an object from list where the objects string property is not in another list<t>'s property

Tags: c#

So I have two lists

`List<ObjectA>` and `List<ObjectB>`

each list contains a string property `ItemID`

I have an issue where if any `ObjectA`'s string property within the list is not found within any of the string property of `ObjectB` within the list, then remove `ObjectA` from the list.

So far here is my code

```
List<string> orderedItemIds = new List<string>();
List<string> shippedItemIds = new List<string>();

for (int y = 0; y <= result.Order_Info.Order_Items.Count - 1; y++)
{
    orderedItemIds.Add(result.Order_Info.Order_Items[y].Item_Id);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= result.Order_Info.Shipments.Count-1; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= result.Order_Info.Shipments[i].Items_Info.Count - 1; x++)
    {
       shippedItemIds.Add(result.Order_Info.Shipments[i].Items_Info[x].Item_Id);
    }
}
```

Now I'm stuck on even if I am able to identify which string isn't in the other list, how am I going to remove that object? Do I just loop through each object of the list I am removing from and check if that string is within the list, if it is then remove it?

Solution:
Thanks to the answer I realized I could flip the logic but I guess I was tunnel visioned.

```
        List<string> orderedItemIds = new List<string>();
        List<OrderShipmentModel> shippedItems = new List<OrderShipmentModel>();
        for (int y = 0; y <= result.Order_Info.Order_Items.Count - 1; y++)
        {
            orderedItemIds.Add(result.Order_Info.Order_Items[y].Item_Id);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= result.Order_Info.Shipments.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= result.Order_Info.Shipments[i].Items_Info.Count - 1; x++)
                if(orderedItemIds.Any(item => item == result.Order_Info.Shipments[i].Items_Info[x].Item_Id))
                    shippedItems.Add(result.Order_Info.Shipments[i]);
        }
```

Comment: `foreach(var objectToRemove in objectAList.Where(objA => !objectBList.Any(objB => objB.ItemID == objA.ItemId)).ToList()) objectAList.Remove(objectToRemove);` (this is an example, but not very performant)

Comment: You can loop/iterate (with or without Linq), but that could be slow if the lists are somewhat larger. I rather suggest you populate a HashSet<string> with the ObjectB ItemIDs (a simple Linq `Select` would make this rather easy) (or, if feasible, turn the ObjectB into a dictionary with the ItemIDs of the ObjectB instances being the keys). Then, use another `Select` on the ObjectA collection, selecting all items whose ItemID are contained within the HashSet/Dictionary. Turn this into a list and you have your resulting ObjectA list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the logic here, instead of removing items from original list, you can create the new list that will contain only `valid` items.

```
class Program
{
    private class MyClass
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listA = new List<MyClass> {
            new MyClass { ItemId = "a"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "b"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "c"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "d"}};

        var listB = new List<MyClass> {
            new MyClass { ItemId = "a"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "b"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "x"},
            new MyClass { ItemId = "y"}};

        var listWithValidItemsOnly = new List<MyClass>();

        foreach (var itemA in listA)
        {
            if (listB.Any(item => item.ItemId == itemA.ItemId))
                listWithValidItemsOnly.Add(itemA);
        }

    }
}
```

I made this example simple to depict the logic here. Keep in mind that for bigger lists, it would be better to convert `listB` to Dictionary so then you will be able to get the presence of any key with O(1) complexity.

Comment: I updated the question with the solution I landed on. I didn't think of flipping the logic but it was a good idea. I still think my code could be more performant but for now this will do.